# Word to describe ability to find anything on the internet

Tags: single-word-requests

I've got a knack for being able to find almost anything on the internet. I'm very tech savvy and know the ways to really get the most out of search engines using symbols and codes to filter results.

Besides that, I seem to be able to identify rather quickly web sites that contain information that's relevant to my research, and those that do not. I can find those little corners of the internet that have the scraps of information I'm looking for. Often, when someone else cannot find information, I'm able to.

I believe there's a word for this type of skill. Several months ago, I thought I had come across the word, but now I seem to have lost it. The irony that I can't find the word to describe my ability to locate lost things on the internet is not lost on me. :)

Does anybody know of a word to describe an ability to excel at research and locating information?

So, rather than saying "That guy is good at finding information." You might say "That guy has great [word] skills." Or "That guy excels at [word]."

I've heard "Google-Fu" before, and it's funny, but I can't put that on a resume.

"Research" is a good word, but I don't feel it quite clearly defines what I'm trying to say.

Comment: content locator whizz.